# higher order derivative in Sympy problem with dummy indecis

Tags: python, sympy, derivative

How to get *k*th derivative of f(x) where *k* is also a dummy index in summation.
sym.diff(f,x,n) is interpreted as derivative of f with respect to both *x* and *k* not as *k*th derivative of f(x) which is what I want.
The problem I have is in this expression

```
sym.Sum((1/sym.factorial(k)*sym.diff(fun,x,k)*(x-a)**k),(k,0,10))
```

Any suggestions?
I want to some over kth derivatives as in taylor series, however, I don't know how to make sympy interpret k as number - order of the derivative (coming from the summation) and not a variable when it comes to the differentiation.
The problem:
[how sum evaluates to zero](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FHyh.png)

[Mistake isn't inside the sum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxNqd.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you want but I guess you need to pass a tuple `(x, k)` like `diff(f, (x, k))` rather than `diff(f, x, k)`. Like this:

```
In [1]: import sympy as sym

In [2]: x, k, a = sym.symbols('x, k, a')

In [3]: fun = Function('f')(x)

In [4]: sym.Sum((1/sym.factorial(k)*sym.diff(fun,(x,k))*(x-a)**k),(k,0,10))
Out[4]: 
  10                      
______                    
╲                         
 ╲                        
  ╲                k      
   ╲           k  d       
    ╲  (-a + x) ⋅───(f(x))
    ╱              k      
   ╱             dx       
  ╱    ───────────────────
 ╱              k!        
╱                         
‾‾‾‾‾‾                    
k = 0 

In [5]: _.doit()
Out[5]: 
            10                      9                     8                     7                     6                     5                
        10 d                    9  d                  8  d                  7  d                  6  d                  5  d                 
(-a + x)  ⋅────(f(x))   (-a + x) ⋅───(f(x))   (-a + x) ⋅───(f(x))   (-a + x) ⋅───(f(x))   (-a + x) ⋅───(f(x))   (-a + x) ⋅───(f(x))   (-a + x
             10                     9                     8                     7                     6                     5                
           dx                     dx                    dx                    dx                    dx                    dx                 
───────────────────── + ─────────────────── + ─────────────────── + ─────────────────── + ─────────────────── + ─────────────────── + ───────
       3628800                 362880                40320                  5040                  720                   120                  

     4                     3                     2                                 
 4  d                  3  d                  2  d                                  
) ⋅───(f(x))   (-a + x) ⋅───(f(x))   (-a + x) ⋅───(f(x))                           
     4                     3                     2                                 
   dx                    dx                    dx                   d              
──────────── + ─────────────────── + ─────────────────── + (-a + x)⋅──(f(x)) + f(x)
  24                    6                     2                     dx
```

Comment: This case should probably be documented with an example in `diff`.

Comment: Thank you!! that solves it, sorry I didn't think of it.